# Highcharts - add event click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add `click` event to that light blue area at the chart. 
[image]
I figured out how to add event click to the column with:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
         point: {
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    alert('clicked');
                }
            }
        },
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
}
```

But don't know how to handle action to whole 'column'.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yyc3L53p/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yyc3L53p/6/ is this what you want done ? @breq

Comment: @RaniMorelesRubillos perfect! thank you!